# math.random always returning 1 in array

Tags: javascript, random

So i ran the code about 50 times and each time it returned olg / 1 so What is wrong

```
alert("welcome to word unscrambler undscramble this")
console.log("i am not a distraction")
document.write("i am not a distraction either")
var r = ["pttoao","recme","logd","teey","olg"]
var g=Math.floor(Math.random() *+ 6);

if (g=="0") {select =("pttoao")}
  else if(g=="1"){select=("recme")}
   else if (g==2){select="logd"}
   else if(g==3){select="dre"}
    else if(g==4){select="olg"}
if(select=="pttoao"){realword="potato"}
if(select=="recme"){realword="creme"}
if(select=="logd"){realword="gold"}
if(select=="teey"){realword="yeet"}
if(select="olg"){realword="log"}
var awnser= prompt("unscramble "+select)
if(awnser==realword){alert("correct")
}else{
  alert("incorrect")}
```

maybe it is that it cant randomly select words

Comment: that is javascript, not java. Also i doubt that the `*+` is valid javascript.

Comment: @codesforkids change the spacing around...  it would get parsed as `Math.random() * +6`

Comment: what should i change it to

Comment: Please elaborate on what the issue is.

Comment: so when you run it it always returns olg as what to unscramble

Comment: `if (select = "olg") {..}` just before `prompt` always sets `select` to "olg", a typo ...

Comment: ty for the awnser

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code that works for any amount of words.
Notice the structure: array of objects, objects have the real word and the scramble of it.
The `random` is relative to the amount of words.
I've combined the prompt, the check, and the alert into one line.
"Simplify by complication..." :)

```js
var words=[
  {real:"potato", scrambled:"pttoao"},
  {real:"creme",  scrambled:"recme"},
  {real:"gold",   scrambled:"logd"},
  {real:"yeet",   scrambled:"teey"},
  {real:"log",    scrambled:"olg"}
];

var random=Math.floor(Math.random()*words.length);
alert(
  prompt("Unscramble: "+words[random].scrambled)
  ==
  words[random].real?
  "Correct":
  "Wrong"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> var g=Math.floor(Math.random() *+ 6 )
> ```
>
> should be replaced with following as array elements index starts from
> zero and array "r" contains 5 elements
>
> ```
>  var g=Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
> ```

---

> ```
> if(select="olg"){realword="log"}
> ```
>
> here, you have assigned "olg" value to select variable. Inside "if" condition assignment   is simply returning assigned value which is "olg" that makes it true and executes `realword="log"`

> It should be replaced with
>
> ```
> if(select=="olg"){realword="log"}
> ```